# AngularJs - Update record and display data from a drop-down list

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, angularjs-directive

**Problem:** I have a grid for which I implemented Create&Update functionality. On create the user gets a modal dialog with some fields and a few drop-down lists (each drop-down is getting populating with data from the db).

The issue I have is with the update. If the user wants to update a record from the grid, he will select the row and click a button which will open a modal dialog that display all record fields in "non-editable mode". The fields will only become editable if the user click the button "Edit" at the bottom of the modal dialog. **The question is:** How to get the drop-down (i.e country list) to display only the data for that specific record in "non-editable mode" (let's say Ireland) and once the user will click the "Edit button" the drop-down to still show the same data(Ireland). Unless the user will click on the drop-down which then will show the entire list of countries so eventually can select a different one.

For the sake of example, I am going to post the current implementation for the country drop-down list. This is the code I am using on Create modal dialog, for the Update modal dialog it should be something similar but no idea on how to display the relevant country of the selected record from the grid.

**Populate the country drop-down**

```
                 <div class="control-group">
                      <label class="control-label">*Country</label>
                      <div class="input-append">
                          <div data-ng-init="getCountryDataFromServer()">
                              <b>Person Data:</b> <select id="countryId" ng-model="contact.countryId">
                              <option value="">-- Select Countries --</option>
                              <option data-ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.countryId}}">{{country.countryname}}</option>
                          </select><br>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-append">
                          <label>
                            <span class="alert alert-error"
                                  ng-show="displayValidationError && newContactForm.countryData.$error.required">
                                <spring:message code="required"/>
                            </span>
                          </label>
                      </div>
                  </div>
```

**Ng-Init Angularjs directive**

```
//Load countries from JSON and populate the dropdown
$scope.getCountryDataFromServer = function() {

    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/tool/protected/country/all'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.countries = data;
        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use ng-options to create a dropdown-list

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="countries.selectedCountry" 
ng-options="country in countries">
</select>
```

Now you only have to set with

```
$scope.countries.selectedCountry = "that country";
```

the country you would like to set.

Edit: I saw, you used contact.countryId as model. You also could use that, but you have to be sure that the value you set is exact the same as in the dropdown.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to understand ur solution, maybe because I am new to Angular. I've come eventually with another solution to my problem. code below in my answer.(I know is a bit of a hack what I am doing but it does the job.)

Comment: You only had to change your own select to that select i showed you. And after that, you can set the value of the select by changing its model. but your solution is also working. good job.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create a input field to show the current country name. This field is set to ng-hide when the modal dialog is in the non-editable mode. If the user click the "edit" button instead of the field I get the drop-down list which is set to ng-show (if modal dialog is in editing mode). On the UI, user wont have a clue of whats happening but behind the scene is quite ugly I think...but still, is a solution to my problem.

**Code**

```
                   <div class="control-group" ng-class="{error: displayValidationError && updateContactForm.country.countryId.$error.required}">
                            <label class="control-label">*Country</label>
                            <div class="controls">
                                <input type="text" autofocus required ng-model="contact.countryId"
                                       name="country.countryname"
                                       placeholder="Status" ng-hide="editingUpdateForm" />
                                <div data-ng-init="getCountryDataFromServer()" ng-show="editingUpdateForm">
                                    <select id="contact.country.countryId" autofocus required ng-model="contact.country.countryId">
                                    <option data-ng-repeat="country in countries" value="{{country.countryId}}">{{country.countryname}}</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="help-inline"
                                  ng-show="displayValidationError && newContactForm.countryData.$error.required">
                                <spring:message code="required"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```